# Regex that contain only alphanumeric and special characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to select all rows that contain only english and special characters in MySQL using:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9 \-\:\(\)\&\.\,\?]+$'
```

I don't know what is wrong when I try adding `- : ( ) & . , ? ! ' | < >`.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: So just add them to your regular expression. You already have half of them. Some of them you'll need to escape obviously.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9 :()&.,?-]+$'`. Yours also returns records with `!`, and `"`, right?

Comment: Yes i need all of them

Comment: Then you must specify **which** symbols you need to add to the regex pattern. We cannot guess which of them must be there. Note also that Unicode symbols cannot be used with MySQL regexp. Otherwise, no one will be able to answer the question but you.

Comment: You must add the requirements to the question (also, sample input that must be matched), else, please remove it. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor it's great

Comment: @motioz: What is great? My suggested `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9 :()&.,?-]+$'` or the answer you accepted? :) Or that I had to vote to close the question :)? Please clarify.

Comment: I think undoing the edit to the question would vastly improve the question itself - but doing it now with all the comments everywhere will only make matters even worse unless somebody cleans those out too.

Comment: Wiktor: your suggestion help me understand how to do it, after i see the answer of swa66, thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The special character i want: `- : ( ) & . , ? ! ' | < >`

Note that when you add characters to a character class, you do not have to blindly escape all of them, and if you have to escape them, you must use a double `\\` backslash in MySQL regex. However, it is not necessary. When you place the `-` hyphen at the start or end of the character class, or right after a POSIX character class, it is treated as a literal hyphen. Other "special" characters you need do not have to be escaped in the character class.

Also, `'` should be doubled in a single quoted string literal.

So, use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9 :()&.,?!''|<>-]+$'
```

Answer (score 1):

As some have commented already all you need to do is add the additional characters to your regexp between the `[` `]`.

Some of them will need to be escaped with a \ in front of them (like the `-` in there has become a `\-` already.

To learn the most out of it: add them one by one.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Comment: Oh, accepted. I do not think *(like the `-` in there has become a ``\-`` already*  is really that helpful.

Comment: It was with the question as it was at the time I wrote ... but the question was edited in the mean time. Hence my earlier comment about the question itself being a moving target... Sorry.

Comment: `-` has special meaning inside regexps -- namely to connote a 'range' of characters, such as `A-Z`.  However, `\-` is turned into `-` _before_ checking for that special meaning.  Hence `'[0-9 \-\:]` looks for a digit or any character between space and colon, identical to `'[0-9 -:]`.  The way to get `-` to be recognized as just the dash character is to put it first (or last) inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not regexp`:

```
select *
from table
where column not regexp '[^A-Za-z0-9:()&.,?!''|<>]';
```

That is, return rows where `column` has a character that is not in your list.

Comment: @swa66 - There are two 'nots', one before `regexp`, one just inside `[^...]`, so it _is_ equivalent.